# How can I output random points under a Laplacian density function in Matlab?

Tags: distributions, matlab, random-generation

E.g. given a Standard Laplacian distribution:

```
g = @(x) 1/(2*1)*exp(-(abs(x-0))/1); %  Std Laplacian distribution
```

How can I produce `n = 1000` points lying under the graph of `g`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From wikipedia:

> A Laplace(0, b) variate can also be generated as the difference of two i.i.d. Exponential(1/b) random variables

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
% Define Laplacian PDF
g = @(x) 1/(2*1)*exp(-(abs(x-0))/1); %  Std Laplacian distribution

% Desired number of points
nSample=1e3;

% Generate rnd random variables
U=rand(nSample,1); % nSample numbers from Uniform(0,1)
X=randn(nSample,1); % nSample numbers from Normal(0,1)

% Plot points
scatter(X, U.*g(X), 'r');
```

### Edit

This **answer is wrong** since as @adamO pointed out, I had just

> generated random normal vars and calculated their image under the density.

Comment: I don't know what c is.  Nevertheless, is this something you did before posting the question and now believe to be wrong, or do you think what you did is correct?  If the latter, would you care to explain why you think this is correct or makes any sense whatsoever? If the former, then rather than providing it as an answer, you could consider adding it with suitable caveat to your original post.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone
Sorry, I removed `c` which is useless to the purpose of the question.

Well what I was trying to do was to plot uniformely distributed points in the area between the Laplacian density function graph and the x-axis. It seems like it's working. But I have the impression you think there is something terribly wrong, so please let me know

Comment: @KillingBambi what you have done is generated random normal vars and calculated their image under the density. This returns results that are bounded above 0. This is the wrong approach.

Comment: @KillingBambi if you want a general approach, you should *invert* the *cumulative* distribution function (obtained by calculating the antiderivative of the density), and then calculate the image of *iid random uniform* realizations under the inverse distribution function.

Comment: @KillingBambi but the approach given in my answer is the easiest.

Comment: @AdamO Now it makes more sense, I will try the Exponential approach. Thank you